# Che cos'è una "pedanca"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Era giunto al piano e si affrettò verso la passerella. Poi si accorse di aver puntato troppo a valle e dovette risalire il torrente di una cinquantina di passi. 
>         Passò sulla **pedanca** fradicia e sbilenca. Il paese oltre il greto era sempre perfettamente silenzioso, formicolava di silenzio.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è una "pedanca"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pedanca è una specie di ponticello che si può trovare in passaggi molto difficili, specie in zone montagnose particolarmente impervie.

In questa [legenda per mappe](http://www.mondogeo.it/Immagini/Pdf/SIMBOLI%20IGM%2025000.pdf) si può leggere:

> Sentiero facile: ponte sospeso
>
> Sentiero difficile: pedanca.

Inoltre, nel comune di Ampezzo c’è il [sentiero della Pedanca del Buso](http://www.ampezzo.org/turismo/itinerari/pedanca), così descritto:

> In corrispondenza della confluenza con il Torrente Novarza, il
>   Torrente Lumiei s’ìnabissa in una spettacolare forra, detta Sac di
>   Coronìs, profonda quasi 130 m e larga solo pochi metri. Le compatte
>   rocce calcaree sono state erose nel corso dei millenni lungo
>   l’andamento di fratture di origine tettonica, dalle acque dei due
>   torrenti. Il luogo è senza dubbio uno dei più selvaggi e spettacolari
>   delle vallate dalla Carnia, e il suo interesse oltre che paesaggistico
>   e ambientale è anche storico. Su un piccolo ponte di legno, detto
>   Pedanca del Buso, posto in corrispondenza di uno dei punti in cui le
>   pareti della forra maggiormente si avvicinano, passava infatti il
>   sentiero che da Ampezzo conduceva a Latéis e a Sauris. Il sentiero
>   cadde in disuso negli anni ‘30, quando fu ultimata la rotabile della
>   valle del Lumiei. Oggi, al posto dell’antica Pedanca del Buso, c’è un
>   ponticello metallico che permette di attraversare la forra e di
>   accedere alle forre del Torrente Novarza e del Torrente Lumiei.

Comment: In questo [*Dizionario delle voci guaste o nuove e piu de' francesismi introdotti nelle lingue militari d'Italia di Mariano d'Ayala*](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_G4WWJ3_OdgQC/bub_gb_G4WWJ3_OdgQC_djvu.txt), del 1855, si può leggere: «Palancola. Pedanca.». Quindi, una "pedanca" sarebbe lo stesso di una "palancola".

Comment: La [definizione del GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000923.jpg) conferma che è lo stesso di una "palancola", cioè, quello che si spiega in questa risposta. Grazie!

Answer (score 1):

Sembra che sia una parola [genovese](https://www.facebook.com/bibidoppio/photos/a.750905491768729.1073741828.750901985102413/848147275377883/?type=1&theater) che ha il significato di "passerella che attraversa un rio".

Comment: Probabilmente è anche piemontese.

Comment: Definitivamente è ["voce di area piemontese"](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000923.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Sulle tavolette militari 1:25.000 dell'IGMI già  nell'edizione del 1959 con tale termine vengono indicate le passerelle temporanee che venivano predisposte temporaneamente tra le rive di un torrente, per raggiungere l'altra sponda, specialmente per lo sfalcio dei prativi a fondo valle.
Costituite da una o due scale a pioli ( p.e. se disponibile un masso in mezzo al torrente ) su cui venivano deposte assi per il passaggio, opportunamente legate alla scala.
Le testate delle scale erano fissate per sicurezza ad alberi o pioli sulla sponda.
Il simbolo cartografico :
>-------<

Comment: Grazie, @Silvio! Adesso, con il [GDLI](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000923.jpg) su Internet è molto più facile trovare il significato di queste parole.